# Can we scan multiple barcodes back to back using zxing.mobile

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, zxing

I am using ZXing.net.mobile 1.4.7.1 in an iOS App. I have the barcode scanning working well. However, it is only setup to scan one barcode at a time. I would like to scan multiple barcodes back to back. Because we use barcodes as checkpoints and each time we scan the barcode, it needs to be uploaded to our server via the web service. I have this part functioning... But it is not efficient to re-activate the scanner controller and wait each time.

Is there an option that will allow us to scan a barcode, display a brief alert for the submitted record then revert back to the scanner controller to continue scanning the next barcode?

Thank you so much in advance for your assistance!!!!

Comment: This might not be possible in ZXing. There are commercial SDK's that allow multiple scanning.

Comment: do you want scan two barcodes that are placed side by side at a time!! or DO you want to scan one by one ?

Comment: Thanks for reply ..... no i want to scan multiple barcode but camera will not closed after one scan. There is only one barcode at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [latest version](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/releases).

Version 1.5 introduced a continuous scanning mode. So you might have to upgrade, to achieve your goal.

Continuous mode leaves the camera open and decoding.

To display the results you might need to use a [custom overlay](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#custom-overlays).

---

If you instead want to read multiple codes on one document in one go, you need to hack your own ZXing.Net.Mobile and use the underlying ZXing.Net features of [GenericMultipleBarcodeReader](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/lib/multi/GenericMultipleBarcodeReader.cs).